# Выравнивание двух inline-block-ов

Tags: html, css

Когда текст одного размера все идеально, но когда размер меняю - начинаются проблемы. Правый блок съезжает вверх, вместо того что бы стоять ровно в ряд. На картинке видно.

Задача в том что бы текст в правом блоке мог иметь разные размеры, ибо иногда туда нужно добавить больше текста.

HTML:

```
<div class="hero_na">
<div class="hero_rname"><span>Текст слева</span></div>
<div class="hero_age"><span style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 22px;height: 22px;">Длинный текст справа меньшего размера</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero_na {display:block;margin-bottom:15px;overflow:hidden;font-size: 0px;transform: skew(-.25rad) perspective(1px) translate3d(0,0,0);}
.hero_na div {display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: verdana;font-size: 20px;height: 22px;}
.hero_na div span {display: inline-block;transform: skew(0.25rad);color:#fff;}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vertical-align: middle;

Comment: @soledar10, к чему его применять? Я уже пробовал, изменений не замечал..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent{
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.child{
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-.25rad) translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: skew(-.25rad) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.child-1{
    background: #FFA500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.child-2{
    background: rgba(65,105,225,0.5);   
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.child > span{
    display: block;    
    -webkit-transform: skew(.25rad) translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: skew(.25rad) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child-1"><span>Текст слева</span></div>
    <div class="child child-2"><span>Длинный текст справа меньшего размера</span></div>
</div>
```